# onContentReady issue with dxSelectBox

Tags: devextreme

I am trying to initialize the value of a dxSelectBox to the first option after load and while it works as expected on the initial load, it doesn't if the dataSource is updated via an option call.

onContentReady is eventually called but only after one clicks in the dropdown.

My understanding from [here](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxForm/Configuration/#onContentReady) is that onContentReady should be triggered immediately after a property change so I am hopeful that there is a workaround.

Here's an example that shows it not automatically selecting the first item after an update to the datasource.  Note that I'm actually using a CustomStore and not an ArrayStore as below but the behaviour is the same.   An ArrayStore would allow for hard coding a reference to the first item in the array, but that's not possible with a CustomStore, thus me using the load in onContentReady.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="change">CLICK ME</div>

<div id="provStateDropdown"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/devextreme/21.2.4/js/dx.all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/devextreme-aspnet-data/2.8.6/dx.aspnet.data.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        let states = new DevExpress.data.ArrayStore({
            key: "id",
            data: [
                { id: 1, label: "Alabama" },
                { id: 2, label: "Alaska" },
                { id: 3, label: "Arizona" }
            ],
        });

        let provinces = new DevExpress.data.ArrayStore({
            key: "id",
            data: [
                { id: 101, label: "Alberta" },
                { id: 102, label: "BC" }
            ],
        });

        let loaded = false;

        $('#provStateDropdown').dxSelectBox({
            dataSource:  states,
            displayExpr: 'label',
            valueExpr: 'id',
            searchEnabled: true,
            onContentReady: function (e) {
                alert('ready called');
                if (!loaded) {
                    loaded = true;
                    e.component.option('dataSource').load().done(function (data) {
                        e.component.option('value', data[0].id);
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        $("#change").click(function() {
            loaded = false;
            $('#provStateDropdown').dxSelectBox('instance').option('dataSource', provinces)
        });
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```